# Culminating numerous workbooks with dynamic arrays to one single workbook, excel

Tags: excel

I will have a defined number of identical workbooks within excel for each member of staff, at present this is 3. I want to have a master workbook where I can consolidate the data from all 3 workbooks. If there was a defined number of inputs I could obviously just copy and paste the data over or use a macro to make it seem more 'live'. However, it will be unknown how many inputs each member of staff will have and the only way I could imagine doing it is by the following equation (however I would use the workbook reference):

```
  =IF(Sheet1!A1<>"",Sheet1!A1,IF(Sheet2!A1<>"",Sheet2!A1,IF(Sheet3!A1<>"",Sheet3!A1,0)))
```

However, when you drag the formula down it will give the obvious problem of putting the value of Sheet2!B13 in the 13th cell if there were only 12 inputs in SheetA, I would need to know the final value of the first sheet to reference the second sheet - but they are dynamic.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you need to now how many rows you have in an area, So check my answer, that can be helpful ;).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the last row of an area by a formula in Excel;
You need `Table`:

1. Select your area.
2. Click on `Formats as Table` from Home→Styles, and select one of then
3. Now you have `DESIGN` tab that you can see the `Table Name` like `Table1`.

Now, you have a table and by this formula you can find number of rows of your table:

```
=ROWS(Table1)
```

And by this formula you can find number of columns of your table:

```
=COLUMNS(Table1)
```

And when you want to know its value try this (The final value):

```
=INDIRECT(T(ADDRESS(ROWS(Table1)+1; COLUMNS(Table1)))
```

> **NOTE :** By using Tables you Don't need to specify your sheet.